# Mark empty fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with the fields structured in the following format:

```
<span class="req">*</span>
<label for="name">Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name">
```

On submit, I would like to mark the empty fields that have an asterisk before them. I assume I can use `.each()` to loop through my form fields, but how do I target only required fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.req').each(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='*') {
        if(!$(this).siblings('input').val()) {//Has no value
            //DO STUFF HERE
        }
    }
});
```

Like this?

Or you could do something like this:

```
$('input').each(function(){
    //IF NO VALUE AND IS REQUIRED
    if(!$(this).val() && $(this).siblings('.req').length != 0) {
        $(this).addClass('error');//AS PRAVEEN SUGGESTS
        alert('Field is required');
    }
});
```

**WARNING**
This code assumes that your `span`, `label` and `input` are inside of another element and don't share other inputs and `.req`'s. Otherwise the `.siblings()` method will return multiple elements.

Comment: Dude, you are making more complicated. But yeah, your code works too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Please give a class say `required` to the `input`s which should not be empty. And use this function:

```
$('.required').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass("error");
    }
});
```

And in the CSS, define `.error` as:

```
.error {border: 1px solid #f00;}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jr8r9/

Comment: I cannot modify input fields, they are dynamically generated.

Comment: @santa You can modify dynamically generated content. It's tricky to attach event listeners to them though. If you are just adding a class or a value, you do it the same as you would a non dynamic element.

Comment: True, but the reason I like to go by the visual indicator as oppose to the class hidden inside input tag, there's no error potential of marking the optional field as required.